# E/ReactNativeJS: No dimension set for key window

Tags: react-native

I don't ask for help when it's nott necessary, but now I'm out of ideas..

I upgraded RN to 0.61.5 and now whatever I do after loading splash screen I'm getting following screen and errors:

[image]

```
12-27 20:16:07.068 26616-26746/com.sleep_tracker D/SoLoader: About to load: libyoga.so
12-27 20:16:07.068 26616-26746/com.sleep_tracker D/SoLoader: libyoga.so not found on /data/data/com.sleep_tracker/lib-main
12-27 20:16:07.068 26616-26746/com.sleep_tracker D/SoLoader: libyoga.so found on /data/app/com.sleep_tracker-2/lib/arm64
12-27 20:16:07.068 26616-26746/com.sleep_tracker D/SoLoader: Not resolving dependencies for libyoga.so
12-27 20:16:07.069 26616-26746/com.sleep_tracker D/SoLoader: Loaded: libyoga.so
12-27 20:16:07.097 26616-26746/com.sleep_tracker D/SoLoader: init exiting
12-27 20:16:07.267 26616-26745/com.sleep_tracker E/ReactNativeJS: No dimension set for key window
12-27 20:16:07.285 26616-26745/com.sleep_tracker E/ReactNativeJS: Module HMRClient is not a registered callable module (calling setup)
12-27 20:16:07.286 26616-26745/com.sleep_tracker E/ReactNativeJS: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Turned out that it was node.js error. Downgraded to v10.16.3 and everything works ;)